# Why the function gives unwanted value

Tags: c#

I have a function like this for binding the primary key from the selected database in a ComboBox:

```
//An instance of the connection string is created to manage the contents of the connection string.

var sqlConnection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlConnection.DataSource = "192.168.10.3";
sqlConnection.UserID = "gp";
sqlConnection.Password = "gp";
sqlConnection.InitialCatalog = Convert.ToString(cmbDatabases.SelectedValue);
string connectionString = sqlConnection.ConnectionString;

SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

//To Open the connection.
sConnection.Open();

//Query to select the table_names that have PRIMARY_KEYS.
string selectPrimaryKeys = @"SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
                             WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                             ORDER BY TABLE_NAME";

//Create the command object
SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand(selectPrimaryKeys, sConnection);

try
{
    //Create the dataset
    DataSet dsListOfPrimaryKeys = new DataSet("INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS");

    //Create the dataadapter object
    SqlDataAdapter sDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectPrimaryKeys, sConnection);

    //Provides the master mapping between the sourcr table and system.data.datatable
    sDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS");

    //Fill the dataset
    sDataAdapter.Fill(dsListOfPrimaryKeys);

    //Bind the result combobox with primary key tables
    DataViewManager dvmListOfPrimaryKeys = dsListOfPrimaryKeys.DefaultViewManager;
    cmbResults.DataSource = dsListOfPrimaryKeys.Tables["INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS"];
    cmbResults.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
    cmbResults.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
    EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
    log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
    log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    //If connection is not closed then close the connection
    if(sConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        sConnection.Close();
}
```

But it is giving an unwanted result like dtproperties.Is anything wrong with the query.

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the current output? We need more details. Have you tried running the query directly against the DB using something like SQL Management Studio?

Comment: yes in query there is proble....It is showing the same result in sql management studio.

Comment: hey, your `SqlConnection` is not disposed at the end of the method!

Comment: So your problem is that you get a list of tables as expected, but 'dtproperties' appears in the list and you don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dtproperties` is a table used by SQL Server to store diagram information. In some versions of SQL Server it is marked as a user table (rather than a system table) and so will get returned by queries that look for user table.

Maybe just filter it out with something like this:

```
string selectPrimaryKeys = @"SELECT 
                                       TABLE_NAME 
                                   FROM
                                       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
                                  WHERE 
                                       CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                                       AND TABLE_NAME <> 'dtproperties'
                               ORDER BY 
                                       TABLE_NAME";
```

Answer (score 0):

Although primary keys are technically part of tables and not databases, assuming your query is correct, try this for your C# code.  It has a few memory and performance improvements, as well as it would catch connection exceptions as well.

```
public void GetPrimaryKeyTable() {
    //An instance of the connection string is created to manage the contents of the connection string.

    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlConnection.DataSource = "192.168.10.3";
    sqlConnection.UserID = "gp";
    sqlConnection.Password = "gp";
    sqlConnection.InitialCatalog = Convert.ToString(cmbDatabases.SelectedValue);

    // Automatically close the connection
    using(SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection.ConnectionString)) {
        try {
            sConnection.Open();

            //Query to select the table_names that have PRIMARY_KEYS.
            string selectPrimaryKeys = @"SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                                        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
                                        WHERE   CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                                        ORDER   BY TABLE_NAME";

            //Create the command object
            using(SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand(selectPrimaryKeys, sConnection)) {
                // Bind the combobox without destroying the data reader object after binding (no using statement)
                cmbResults.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
                cmbResults.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";  
                cmbResults.DataSource sReader = sCommand.ExecuteReader();
                cmbResults.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            // All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
            EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
            log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
            log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }
        finally {
            // Read somewhere that the using statement takes care of this for you
            // but just in case
            if(sConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) {
                sConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for your query, in SQL Server 2008 R2, it returns a list of tables that have primary keys (each table in the list is a table with a primary key).  What version of SQL Server are you using?

EDIT: If you want your query to only return USER tables and filter out things like system tables, try this query:

```
SELECT  tc.TABLE_NAME 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
INNER   JOIN sysobjects so
        ON tc.TABLE_NAME = so.name
WHERE   tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        AND so.xtype = 'U'
ORDER   BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: My fault, the method name is ExecuteReader() not ExecuteDataReader(). I've updated my answer to reflect this.